# MySQL Trigger Insert / Update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I hope you can help me with a trigger.

I have [two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PYHI.png) `Books` and `Order_Details`.
I want the trigger to update `InStock` whenever a book from the table `Books` with the same `OrderID` is sold (Quantity)

Can you help me finish the trigger
All i have now is the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateInStock 
    BEFORE insert ON Order_Details
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    Update Books
    SET action = 'update',
        BookID = BookID,
    .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call a simple `UPDATE` statement, to subtract the `InStock` value using `New.Quantity`.

Check the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS UpdateInStock $$
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateInStock 
    BEFORE insert ON Order_Details
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    Update Books
    SET InStock = InStock - New.QUANTITY 
    WHERE BookID = New.BookID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```